# Entity Framework foreign key does not work. Get always returns a NULL object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

As an example, I have a book that is assigned an author. I can create this dataset via EF. But I can't get this dataset back.

AuthorModel:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
```

BookModel:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public int Pages { get; set; }
public AuthorModel Author { get; set; }
```

This is how I create the book and add it to the database:

```
BookModel newBook = new()
{
     Title = "Mathematics for dummies",
     Description = "Its that what the Title says!",
     Pages = 666,
     Author = new AuthorModel()
     {
          FirstName = "Max",
          LastName = "Musterman",
          Birthday = DateTime.Now
     }
};


_db.books.Add(newBook);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Everything works, the foreign key is also set in the database. But when I now want to get exactly the book comes something like this:

```
BookModel book = _db.books.FirstOrDefault(id => id.Id == 1);
```

[image: 1]

As you can see, I get my book, but the author object is NULL.

What would I have to do so that the author is not NULL?

Comment: `_db.books.Include(x => x.Author).FirstOrDefault(id => id.Id == 1);`

Comment: Does your database store objects? Or just basic values? If it's basic values only, I would make a .ToString() method in you Author object that just stores the values as a single string in the db, then reads them and assigns them to their respective variables on retrieval.

Comment: @Jonesopolis so if I understood correctly. I tell him that I have a foreign key and want to set it as author. but if I now have two or more. how should he know what I mean? and how would it look if I had more?

Comment: @JoshHeaps actually it is only a mariadb, so only values

Comment: @Jonesopolis are u still here? i have another question about include. But would not like to create a new question.